# Ошибка "command denied" Hibernate при попытке выполнения команд с удалённое базой MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, база-данных, hibernate

Здравствуйте. При попытке выполнить команду (любую) с удалённой базой данных в Hibernate вижу ошибку:

```
июн 27, 2016 7:44:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
WARN: SQL Error: 1142, SQLState: 42000
июн 27, 2016 7:44:51 PM org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper logExceptions
ERROR: INSERT command denied to user 'a0080939_zzoorm'@'178.215.96.5' for table 'chats'
Exception in thread "main" org.hibernate.exception.SQLGrammarException: INSERT command denied to user 'a0080939_zzoorm'@'178.215.96.5' for table 'chats'
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.convert(SQLExceptionTypeDelegate.java:82)
    at org.hibernate.exception.internal.StandardSQLExceptionConverter.convert(StandardSQLExceptionConverter.java:49)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:125)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.spi.SqlExceptionHelper.convert(SqlExceptionHelper.java:110)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:129)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractProxyHandler.invoke(AbstractProxyHandler.java:81)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy9.executeUpdate(Unknown Source)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.batch.internal.NonBatchingBatch.addToBatch(NonBatchingBatch.java:56)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3028)
    at org.hibernate.persister.entity.AbstractEntityPersister.insert(AbstractEntityPersister.java:3469)
    at org.hibernate.action.internal.EntityInsertAction.execute(EntityInsertAction.java:88)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.execute(ActionQueue.java:362)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:354)
    at org.hibernate.engine.spi.ActionQueue.executeActions(ActionQueue.java:275)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.AbstractFlushingEventListener.performExecutions(AbstractFlushingEventListener.java:326)
    at org.hibernate.event.internal.DefaultFlushEventListener.onFlush(DefaultFlushEventListener.java:52)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.flush(SessionImpl.java:1213)
    at org.hibernate.internal.SessionImpl.managedFlush(SessionImpl.java:402)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.internal.jdbc.JdbcTransaction.beforeTransactionCommit(JdbcTransaction.java:101)
    at org.hibernate.engine.transaction.spi.AbstractTransactionImpl.commit(AbstractTransactionImpl.java:175)
    at ru.syndicategames.mud.Main.main(Main.java:30)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.application.AppMain.main(AppMain.java:144)
Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: INSERT command denied to user 'a0080939_zzoorm'@'178.215.96.5' for table 'chats'
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:411)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.getInstance(Util.java:386)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.SQLError.createSQLException(SQLError.java:1054)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4120)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.checkErrorPacket(MysqlIO.java:4052)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sendCommand(MysqlIO.java:2503)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.MysqlIO.sqlQueryDirect(MysqlIO.java:2664)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.ConnectionImpl.execSQL(ConnectionImpl.java:2815)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeInternal(PreparedStatement.java:2155)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2458)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2375)
    at com.mysql.jdbc.PreparedStatement.executeUpdate(PreparedStatement.java:2359)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.hibernate.engine.jdbc.internal.proxy.AbstractStatementProxyHandler.continueInvocation(AbstractStatementProxyHandler.java:122)
    ... 21 more
```

Проблема в том, что я спокойно выполняю эти команды из MySQL Workbench, например. На удалённой базе никаких ограничений на пользователя нету. С локальными базами всё работает отлично.

Два примера-сравнения, как я заполняю.

В файле **hibernate.cfg.xml** (так не работает)

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='utf-8'?>
<!DOCTYPE hibernate-configuration PUBLIC
        "-//Hibernate/Hibernate Configuration DTD//EN"
        "http://www.hibernate.org/dtd/hibernate-configuration-3.0.dtd">
<hibernate-configuration>
    <session-factory>
    <property name="connection.url">jdbc:mysql://myhost.ru:3306/a0080939_mud</property>
    <property name="connection.driver_class">com.mysql.jdbc.Driver</property>
    <property name="connection.username">a0080939_zzoorm</property>
    <property name="connection.password">12345</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.characterEncoding">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.connection.charSet">UTF-8</property>
    <property name="hibernate.dialect">org.hibernate.dialect.MySQLDialect</property>
    <property name="hibernate.show_sql">true</property>
    <property name="hibernate.current_session_context_class">thread</property>
    <mapping class="ru.syndicategames.mud.dao.Chat"/>
</session-factory>
```

В **MySQL Workbench** (так работает)
[image: MySQL Workbench]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

В логе ясно указано для кого запрещен доступ: `a0080939_zzoorm'@'178.215.96.5`. В MySQL можно создавать более одного пользователя с одним и тем же именем, но с разным адресом. Соответственно, для каждого из пользователей могут быть разные права доступа. При подключении к БД обычно указывается только имя пользователя, а адрес подставляется неявно, что может привести к путанице.

Подключитесь к БД под root-ом и выполните команду:

```
select user, host from mysql.user;
```

Скорее всего, Вы увидите несколько пользователей с одним и тем же именем `a0080939_zzoorm`, но с разным значением `host`. Если Вы осуществляете вход в командную строку `mysql`, находясь на сервере, то используется адрес `localhost`. Если же ваше программное обеспечение подключается к MySQL с другого сервера, то используется адрес этого сервера. Вы можете разрешить пользователю `a0080939_zzoorm` подключаться **с любого адреса**, и выдать **полные права** следующей командой:

```
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO a0080939_zzoorm@"%" IDENTIFIED BY '12345' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

Либо дать права только на `INSERT` на все таблицы и только для пользователя `a0080939_zzoorm` с адресом `178.215.96.5`:

```
GRANT INSERT ON *.* TO a0080939_zzoorm@"178.215.96.5" IDENTIFIED BY '12345' WITH GRANT OPTION;
```

*Выдача полных прав и разрешение подключения с любого адреса заметно снижает безопасность вашей БД, будьте осторожны.*

Answer (score 1):

У пользователя a0080939_zzoorm недостаточно прав для выполнения этого действия.
Авторизируйтесь в mysql как a0080939_zzoorm и выполните команду

```
SHOW GRANTS;
```

Она покажет на что пользователь имеет права, в данном случае права на `INSERT` будут отсутствовать

Чтобы получить права, используйте команду

```
GRANT INSERT ON 'db'.'tablename' TO 'username'@'localhost'
```

Для выполнения этой команды надо быть авторизированным как root.

Comment: Проверил. Права на INSERT присутствуют.

Comment: Тем не менее, эта ошибка говорит именно о недостатке прав.
Проверьте под каким пользователем Вы проверяли права.